# Android CDD/CTS complaince for non telephony devices

Tags: android, android-compatibility

I would like to know if Android is developed to a non telephony device, is there any strict CDD/CTS requirements that has to be complied in order to get Google certification? I am aware of some products such as tablets,TV and other terminals which supports Android but no telephony, this means that Android can be ported to non telephony device and yet Google certified.?

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any strict CDD/CTS requirements that has to be complied in order to get Google certification?

Yes.

> this means that Android can be ported to non telephony device and yet Google certified.?

Yes. However, details of Honeycomb's CDD/CTS are not publicly published at this time.

Comment: Update: Details of CDD/CTS for ICS (Android 4.0) is freely available now (http://source.android.com/compatibility/overview.html)